# Difference between cfn-init and SSM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-systems-manager

I know the basic overview of them, but what is the practical scenario for each of them?

As cfn-init used to bootstrap the servers and SSM helps to execute the commands via ssm documents.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, cfn-init is used to bootstrap a server when it is initially created.

The Amazon System Manager is used to maintain a server afterwards. System Manager can be used to ensure ongoing security patch compliance, install software updates, run ad-hoc commands, etc.